# Typescript function converted to Immutable.js Typescript List

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I'm trying to convert my function to new function using Immutable.js List Methods

In my class i have

```
public checkVisible:any = [];

public rowChecked(index){
        if (this.checkVisible.indexOf(index) === -1) {
            this.checkVisible.push(index);
        }
        else {
            this.checkVisible.splice(this.checkVisible.indexOf(index), 1);
            console.log(this.checkVisible);
        }
    }
```

Trying to convert to this :

```
public checkVisible:Immutable.List<any> = Immutable.List([]);

public rowChecked(index){
    if (this.checkVisible.indexOf(index) === -1) {
        this.checkVisible = this.checkVisible.push(index);
    }
    else {
        this.checkVisible = this.checkVisible.delete(index);
        console.log(this.checkVisible, 'REMOVED');
    }
}
```

first function works as needed :

```
this.rowChecked(0);
this.rowChecked(2);
this.rowChecked(2);
this.rowChecked now is Array[1] = [0:0]
```

But the immutable list function do this:

```
this.rowChecked(0);
this.rowChecked(2);
this.rowChecked(2);
this.rowChecked now is Array[2] = [0:0, 1:2]
```

Which does not satisfy me it seems I do not use the Immutable List Methods properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case, you try to delete by index. In the first case by value. This is not the same. You need to change the line

```
this.checkVisible = this.checkVisible.delete(index);
```

to

```
this.checkVisible = this.checkVisible.delete(this.checkVisible.indexOf(index))
```

Renameing `index` to `value` will reduce confusion.